# Forward slash "/" vs. os.path.join() for MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django, modelform

I have a form (model form) that sends data(such as images, title, etc.) with POST request.

In setting.py file, for MEDIA_ROOT, I tried 2 approach:

1- Forward slash "/"  :

   `MEDIA_ROOT = [ BASE_DIR / 'static/images' ]`

2- os.path.join():

`MEDIA_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')`

When I use the first one(forward slash), I get the below error:

> TypeError at admin/projects/project/...
> _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

Do you know why I can't use the **forward slash "/"** for MEDIA_ROOT while this way it completely works for STATICFILES_DIRS?

Answer (score 2):

[**`MEDIA_ROOT`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) is a single path, so for example:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'  # 🖘 no list
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but why doesn't give an error, using the list for STATICFILES_DIRS ?

Comment: @marziyehseifi: because as the name suggest, `DIRS` is a *list* (or at least a collection) of dirs, not a single dir.